# Underlying implementation of ref for value types

Tags: c#

I was curious how refs are created under the hood for `structs`. If I pass an non-value type as a ref parameter it makes sense that it's the reference to that object.

But for Value types I'm curious, does the run-time create an actual reference (with indirection) or the pointer to actual address

Comment: You are talking about parameters, not `ref struct`s yes?

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you want to know? Is it a curiosity thing? Something else?

Comment: https://adamsitnik.com/ref-returns-and-ref-locals/ and http://mustoverride.com/managed-refs-CLR/ may be worth a read. Same for https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value types are copied, reference types are passed by reference. If you ref a struct you get a pointer to the struct. if you ref a reference type you get a pointer to the instance.

ref value types are useful for being able to change the value the calling function has.
ref reference types are useful for being able to change which instance the calling function has.

Hood peeks:

Depending your performance needs you may not need to know any of this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/

Reference types are created on the heap, Value types are usually created on the stack.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-know-the-difference-passing-a-struct-and-passing-a-class-to-a-method

Comment: Is that really the case? ref of an object is the pointer to the instance? That doesn't sound right because if the object was moved by GC the pointer would be invalid

Comment: Otherwise, the MSDN in your comment answers this. Thanks